# Unable to locate package python-software-properties-common

Tags: software-installation, python

I got this error message when trying to install python-software-properties-common:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-software-properties-common
```

Comment: You haven't said what release; but that package is available for 16.04/xenial - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python-software-properties in 'universe', but your actual issue may vary on your release.   (ps: *that link provides clues on other releases too.. but as we weren't provided with your release you'll have to interpret your issue yourself*)

Answer (score 1):

The package that you are trying to install is named *software-properties-common*, not python-software-properties-common. To install software-properties-common in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

*software-properties-common* provides an abstraction of the used apt repositories. It allows you to easily manage your distribution and independent software vendor software sources.